# Reveal sidebar in Atom (editor)?

Tags: atom-editor

I have a simple question. I've installed Atom and the package nuclide-commons, but when I open a folder, I don't see any sidebar with the list of files in Atom. I'm trying to find a way/shortcut to show it, but I failed. It's even not mentioned in
the main menu...

Any hint? Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

The shortcut is `ctrl-\` or `cmd-\` to open/close the Tree View

Comment: doesn't work for me on Atom 1.22.1 even if in the top bar I can find the option and the keybinding is the same.

Answer (score 3):

Ok, I had to enable the tree-view package in Atom settings. It was not enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows:
Toggle Tree View [CtrK CtrB]

Or Ctr + Shift + P:
Search: Toggle Tree View

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED
step 1. click on the menubar
step 2. click the file menu bar
step 3. finally click the open folder and select the folder you will get side bar 
I hope, you solved it.